# Refering to class instance in another class

Tags: python

I'm writing code that has two classes. The one class creates text elements for a 3-D environment. The other will group them together in that environment. What I'm trying to do is have the second class call instances of the first class. In other words, in `def makeGroup` I want to be able to call an instance of `class msg`.  How would the coding be worded?  Currently, the first class is inherited into the second, and then I'm trying to call the object self.text, but I don't know how I should refer to it.  I don't believe I'm quite using inheritance correctly.

```
class msg:
    def __init__(self,num,unit):
        self.message = str(num) + ' ' + unit
        self.num = num
        self.text = viz.addText(self.message)

class msgGroup(msg):
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.msgLs=[]
        self.ghostMsg= viz.addText('',pos=[x,y,z],color= [0.000, .9, 0.071])
        self.msgLs.append(self.ghostMsg)

    def makeGroup(self):
        msg.text.setPosition([0,(len(self.msgLs)-1)*-1.5,0], viz.REL_PARENT)
        self.msgLs.append(msg.text)
```

Comment: Do you have a question? What is your problem? See http://sscce.org/ and http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five things:

1. If this is Python 2, your `msg` class should inherit from `object`
2. [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): If you don't follow this, no-one will be able to follow your code
3. If `msgGroup` inherits from `msg`, then every `msgGroup` instance also has all of the members (data, methods, and more exotic things) that an instance of `msg` has. In your method `makeGroup`, to refer to the current instance's `text` member, just do `self.text`.
4. You probably want each `msgGroup` to have several `msg`s. To do that, don't use inheritance, just have the `msgGroup` have a list of `msg`s, and iterate over it:

   ```
   for msg in self.msg_list:
       print msg.text
   ```
5. Referring to a member of an object or class is not called "calling it". You call functions, methods, and other callables (like classes), using the `()` operator.

   ```
   foo = self.makeGroup # assigning makeGroup to a variable
   bar = self.makeGroup() # calling makeGroup, then assigning the result of that call to a variable
   ```

Comment: If I make a list of `msg`s wouldn't that still be part of `class msg`? Is there another way to make that list besides putting something like `list.append(self.text)` at the end of the function?

Comment: No, the list of `msg`s will be in an instance of a `msgGroup` class. If you have collected all the data you need or can get it on-the-fly, there are other ways of creating and adding elements to a list, such as `msg_list += [whatever]` or using something commonly called a list comprehension, which is code that will create a list in a single statement. There's more information about them in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comprehension#list-displays).

Comment: @martineau How does the `msgGroup` instance hold the `msgs` if it doesn't use another datastructure? You roll your own linked list in your own answer - in this answer, high-level collections use built-in collections.

Comment: @user1496630 No, a list of `msg`s will not magically become a part of the `msg` class.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, I worded that poorly.  What I was asking is if I make a list in `msgGroup` how would I be able to tell it to add an object from another class? Can I say something to the effect of "append this object from this instance of class msg"?

Comment: @user1496630 I am describing a list which contains instances of `msg`. The list will be composed of instances of `msg`. Now look at point 4 again.

Comment: @Marcin: My comment was answering @user1496630 earlier question, not a critique of your answer (which I upvoted). Anyway, `msgGrup` instances could contain another data structure, called `msg_list` of type `list` to which instances of class `msg` are added as the group is formed. Note it doesn't need to be a roll-your-own linked list or otherwise custom-made, rather just an instance of Python's standard built-in `list` would do fine. You currently don't show this in the little bit of code in your answer which I think is what prompted user1496630's follow-up question in their comment.

Comment: @martineau Ah, I think we are on perfect agreement.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have indeed misunderstood inheritance. Inheritance is for when class B shares all the same properties as class A but has some more, perhaps more specific: eg a Man is a Person.

Your case is different: you have a group, and a group has messages. This is composition, not inheritance: "has-a", not "is-a". You should simply define a message_list inside `msgGroup`, and add messages to it, then you can iterate through the messages and access their `text` attribute.